# Selected Item not updating in BottomNavigationBar Flutter

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, dart

When I am on the booking screen and then switch to teams, highlights, or any other option in order, upon pressing back on those screens, the selected item in the bottom navigation bar remains fixed and does not change when the screen goes back.

For example, when I press on the stats item in the bottom navigation bar and then navigate to the stats screen, upon pressing the back button, the screen changes to the previous one. However, in the bottom navigation bar, the stats item is still shown as selected with the green color, instead of indicating the current screen.

Below is the code for the HomeView Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/screens/main/bookings.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/screens/main/choose_match.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/screens/main/create_team.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/screens/main/edit_team.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/screens/main/highlights.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/screens/main/stats.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/screens/main/venue_screen.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/screens/main/your_teams.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/widgets/highlights_widget.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/widgets/sidebar.dart';
import 'package:sportifan_user/widgets/top_navigation_bar.dart';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> with RouteAware {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  void onTap(int index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/');
        break;
      case 1:
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/teams');
        break;
      case 2:
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/highlights');
        break;
      case 3:
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/stats');
        break;
    }
  }

  final RouteObserver<PageRoute> routeObserver = RouteObserver<PageRoute>();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context) as PageRoute);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didPopNext() {
    _updateCurrentIndex();
  }

  void _updateCurrentIndex() {
    // Define this method to update currentIndex based on the current route
    switch (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name) {
      case '/':
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = 0;
        });
        break;
      case '/teams':
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = 1;
        });
        break;
      case '/highlights':
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = 2;
        });
        break;
      case '/stats':
        setState(() {
          currentIndex = 3;
        });
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController teamController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController uidController = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (navigatorKey.currentState?.canPop() ?? false) {
          navigatorKey.currentState?.pop();
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
            _updateCurrentIndex(); // Add this line
          });
          return false; // Prevent the default back button behavior
        }
        return true; // Allow the default back button behavior if there's no route to pop
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Color(0xFF238F20),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(72.0), // Set the height here
              child: TopNavigationBar(
                controller: controller,
                onNotificationIconTapped: () {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
                },
              ),
            ),
            drawer: SideBar(
              notificationExists: true,
            ),
            body: NotificationListener<PopNavigatorNotification>(
              onNotification: (notification) {
                _updateCurrentIndex();
                return true;
              },
              child: Navigator(
                key: navigatorKey,
                initialRoute: '/',
                onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
                  WidgetBuilder builder;
                  switch (settings.name) {
                    case '/':
                      builder = (BuildContext _) => BookingView();
                      break;
                    case '/teams':
                      builder = (BuildContext _) => YourTeams();
                      break;
                    case '/highlights':
                      builder = (BuildContext _) =>
                          HighlightsView(highlightsExists: true);
                      break;
                    case '/stats':
                      builder =
                          (BuildContext _) => StatsView(statsExists: true);
                      break;
                    default:
                      throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
                  }
                  return MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: builder, settings: settings);
                },
              ),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                canvasColor: Colors.white,
                primaryColor: Color(0xFF238F20),
                textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                      caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                bottomNavigationBarTheme: BottomNavigationBarThemeData(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  elevation: 0,
                ),
              ),
              child: BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: currentIndex,
                onTap: onTap,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.book,
                    ),
                    label: 'Booking',
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.people),
                    label: 'Teams',
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.sports_cricket),
                    label: 'Highlights',
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.graphic_eq),
                    label: 'Stats',
                  ),
                ],
                selectedItemColor:
                    Color(0xFF238F20), // change this to your preferred color
                unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
                showSelectedLabels: true,
                showUnselectedLabels: true,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PopNavigatorNotification extends Notification {}
```

I put in a lot of effort, as you'll see when going through the code, but unfortunately, I gained nothing in return. If someone can help, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would try swapping around these lines in the onWillPop function:

```
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
            _updateCurrentIndex(); 
          });
          navigatorKey.currentState?.pop();
```